# Downloading a Core Data / SQLite Database into an app ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Would it theoretically be possible to download a Core Data database straight into an app and then access this database ?

If so what formatting considerations would there be - would any SQLite database work or would a specific structure be required ?

Comment: Yes this could work, just like any other SQLite database reader. Every SQLite database has metadata about its structure which you could rea. Any coredata SQLite database can be read in the same way.

Comment: No, any SQLite database won't work. Apple uses proprietary SQLite format. You can pregenerate a database during development and then upload to your server.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Core Data's database structure is closed meaning that you cannot and should not attempt to replicate it.  The only recommended way to download a pre-populated database is to use Core Data.  Fortunately OS X and iOS share the exact same structure (and will do so going forward).

The recommended way to handle this is to write a CLI for OS X that generates the SQLite file for you.  Then you can download that file into your application as needed.  This is also recommended for shipping a pre-populated database with your application (which is usually a better option than downloading an entire file).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the CLI tool mentioned by Marcus Zarra is to create a full GUI Mac app. With Cocoa bindings this is very straightforward, and will give you a visual editor for your pre-packaged database as well.

I've written about this concept [here](http://mubaloo.com/news-info/making-a-metaapp-helper-mac-apps-for-ios-developers) and there is an example project [on GitHub](https://github.com/jrturton/Cross-platform-core-data) which contains both Mac and iOS apps.